# Is is possible to have both drivers and keyframes on a single object? (3.0)

Tags: animation, keyframes, drivers

In After Effects it is possible to bind property of object 1 e.g. *X rotation* to same property *X rotation* of object 2 and still have control of self values with possibility of keyframing it.

Example of this case:

> Object 2 has 360 X rotation in 5 seconds. Object 1 will also rotate
> 360 on X but also we can add more rotation keyframes between.

I've found that to bind a property a driver has to be created with simple math expression. In this case it would be just `var` and copying *X rotation* in its settings. Then comes hard part which I can't overcome since I don't see `add keyframe` option while having a driver nor I understand how to bind that in expression. I've also tried adding another input variable of self *X rotation* but now it adds way too much degrees.

Is it possible to do the same trick in Blender without creating every time an empty for each property I want to link? Can I have driver and keyframes at once?

Comment: What do you want those extra rotation keyframes to do?  Do you want them to replace your driven values?  Do you want them to replace your driven values, only at certain times?  Do you want them to act as additional rotation on top of your driven keyframes?

Comment: @Nathan I want then to act as additional rotation on top, yes

Comment: For transforms, you should probably be looking at a layer of parents: you drive the parents, the children inherit transforms and can be keyframed on top.  For single values, say constraint influence, you might consider including custom properties in your driver expressions; then you just keyframe those custom properties.

Comment: @Nathan do you know any tutorial on custom properties and their drivers?

Comment: Sorry, I'd just be Googling, same as you.  Not too hard to figure out without any tutorials though.  Play on properties/object/custom properties.